# Jquery returns json as string

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

I am sending json object from `PHP` to `Jquery ajax`

I am able to receive json data but in string format instead of object.

PHP code

```
$userdata=json_encode(array("FirstName"=> $fName,"LastName"=>$lName,"PhoneNumber"=>$phone,"EmailId"=> $email,"Balance"=>$balance));
echo $userdata;
```

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  alert();
  $.ajax({
    type:"post",
    url:"viewprofile.php",
    contentType: "json",
    data:{"somedata":"anydata"},
    success:function(response) {
      alert(response);
      $.each(response, function(key, value) {
        alert(key + ' ' + value);
      });
    }, 
    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
      alert("error : "+xhr.status+" "+thrownError);     
    }
  });
});
```

I am getting entire json in first alert of success function

But when i iterate over json it returns index and value from a string.

```
For Example
```

in first alert output is `{"fname":"abc","lname":"def"}`

during iteration output is

```
0 {  
1 "  
2 f  
3 n  
4 a  
5 m  
.......so on
```

Am i wrong any where,Please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PHP, by default, declares that its output is HTML. Consequently, you are processing `data` as a string of (invalid) HTML.

Add:

```
header("Content-Type: application/json");
```

---

Also remove `contentType: "json",` from the JavaScript. That is not a valid content-type, and you aren't encoding the data you are POSTing as JSON.